# My app is not appearing in the list of share targets on Samsung devices

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, intentfilter

I am developing an app for Android that will allow the user to share any type of file and have it sync to a service online. In the Android Emulator (Android 13) it works fine, I can share a photo or other file and the app appears in the list of apps I can use to share the file with, the code works, the file does the thing and uploads.

However when I put the app on my Samsung S23 Ultra and I try to share a file, my app doesn't appear in the list of apps I can share with.

Does anyone know what the heck is going on?

My activity setup is as follows:

```
<activity android:exported="true" android:label="MySync" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:name="crc6496e771d188809a74.ShareReceiver">
  <intent-filter android:label="Send To MySync">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I developed the activity as outlined in various sources. I have tried the app on the Emulator and it works as expected.

The moment I load the app on my Samsung device it no longer appears in the Share UI.